# Wordpress title limiting to 15 characters

Tags: wordpress

I am using wordpress and I want to show upto 15 characters for my post title.

I have used this:

```
$myposts = get_posts('numberposts=11&offset=0');
foreach($myposts as $post) :
        substr(the_title(), 0, 15);
endforeach;
```

I have removed the PHP tags to look properly here...basically the code is marked as bold.

but it is not working.

Any suggestion is highly appreciable.

Answer (score 2):

`the_title()` outputs the title directly instead of returning it. Use `get_the_title()` instead.

```
<?php echo substr(get_the_title(), 0, 15)?>
```

Answer (score -1):

i prefer this one

```
echo mb_strimwidth(get_the_title(), 0, 40, '...');
```